# JS - summing elements of arrays

Tags: javascript, operations

I'm trying to make operations with numbers that are stored in arrays, unfortunately they seem to be considered as "text" rather than numbers, so when I do like array1[i] + array2[i], instead of doing 2+3=5 I would get 2+3=23 ...

The values of these arrays come from  fields (html)

No idea how to deal with that ;D
Thanks for your help

If you wanna look at my code, here's what it looks like :

```
        var polynome = [];
        for (var i=0; i<=degree; ++i) {
            polynome[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
        }
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;

        var tempArray = [];
        var quotient = [];

        quotient[degree+1] = 0;

        for (var i=degree; i>=0; --i) {
            tempArray[i] = a * quotient[i+1];
            quotient[i] = polynome[i] + tempArray[i];
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = polynome + "<br>" + tempArray + "<br>" + quotient;
```

Answer (score 2):

`array1[i]` contains string and not int so when you are trying both elements with `+` operator it is concatenating both the values rather of adding them

you need to cast both elements in arrays to integer

try this

```
parseInt( array1[i] ) + parseInt( array2[i] )
```

Comment: Best practice is to include the radix too: `parseInt(array1[i], 10)`

Comment: another way is to use array1[i] * 1 + array2[i] * 1

Answer (score 0):

The `+` punctuator is overloaded an can mean [addition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), concatenation and [conversion to number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6). To ensure it's interpreted as addition, the operands must be numbers. There are a number of methods to convert strings to numbers, so given:

```
var a = '2';
var b = '3';
```

the unary + operator will convert integers and floats, but it's a bit obscure:

```
+a + +b
```

*parseInt* will convert to integers:

```
parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
```

*parseFloat* will convert integers and floats:

```
parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

The Number constructor called as a function will convert integers and floats and is semantic:

```
Number(a) + Number(b);
```

Finally there is the [unary `-` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7), but it's rarely used since subtraction (like multiplication and division) converts the operands to numbers anyway and it reverses the sign, so to add do:

```
a - -b
```